# What software for video editing should a G5 Tower Use?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, mac, leopard, powerpc

My friend has a G5 Tower and would like to create some music videos for his band. I've looked into Final Cut Pro, but unfortunately the latest version is Intel only.

I assume if we went that route, he would need Final Cut Pro 5?

What are his alternatives? For now it would be safe to say the development would be done as a hobby.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

iMovie, part of [Apple's iLife suite](https://www.apple.com/ilife/), is an affordable video editing solution for a hobbyist.